# Unit Testing Job Component C#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to bring a legacy project under test. The code was written in such a way that it is generally testable, however some of the third party dependencies were not. I'm trying to wrap my head around how to unit test something that looks like this:

```
class InsightEmailJob : NHibernateJob
{
    public IInsightEmailService InsightEmailService { get; set; }
    public IReportService ReportService { get; set; }
    public ITemplatedNotifier TemplatedNotifier { get; set; }
    public string ReplyEmail { get; set; }
    public string ReplyName { get; set; }

    public InsightEmailJob(ISession session,
        ILog log,
        IInsightEmailService insightEmailService,
        IReportService reportService,
        ITemplatedNotifier templatedNotifier,
        SystemReplyEmailSpec systemReplyEmailSpec)
        : base(session, log)
    {
        InsightEmailService = insightEmailService;
        ReportService = reportService;
        TemplatedNotifier = templatedNotifier;
        ReplyEmail = systemReplyEmailSpec.ReplyEmail;
        ReplyName = systemReplyEmailSpec.ReplyName;
    }

    public int AccountID{ get; set; }
    private Account mAccount;

    public Account Account
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.mAccount == null)
            {
                mAccount = this.InsightEmailService.Get<Account>(AccountID);
            }
            return mAccount;
        }
    }


    protected override void DoWork(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var insightEmail = InsightEmailService.FindAndIncrementEmailForAccount(Account);
        var report = ReportService.LoadMultiReportByName(insightEmail.ReportName);
        var reportData = ReportService.Execute(report, new ParameterValuesDictionary(Account, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7), DateTime.Now, 0));
        var templateData = new Hashtable {{"data", reportData}, {"account", Account}};
        foreach (var u in Account.Users.Where(x => x.Notify))
        {
            TemplatedNotifier.Send(u.UserName, ReplyName, ReplyEmail, insightEmail.TemplateName, templateData);
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that a lot of people would suggest using Mocks or Stubs to pass in instead of the interfaces, however I'm a little confused as to how this is actually beneficial. It seems that this would just ensure that the appropriate methods are called, which strikes me as somewhat vacuous, and far too coupled with the implementation of the job to be a really valid test. Ultimately the question becomes, how do you unit test something that returns no values and really only causes side effects without just testing that its implemented the way you say it is?

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests are written to prove your implementations work correctly. If your test code is getting too complex and things are becoming harder to mock, implementation code is probably getting more complex and harder to understand as well.

When you decide there is too much work in mocking dependencies, you should reconsider your design and aim to refactor it to a simpler form.

Just by looking at your constructor we can see that it's probably doing too much work. You have 6 dependencies and you will have to mock all of them to write valid unit tests. I don't think you have enough abstractions here because you have to deal with NHibernate sessions, some reporting service and send an email.

[Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) is a common pattern for abstracting data access code. You also should move email sending part to another class and use its interface here.

It's pretty easy to mock methods that don't have a return value. By mocking these method calls you prove that your class is using external dependencies correctly.You can write asserts for parameter values and how many times it is called to validate your code.

Anyway here's an example of how you can mock a method in [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/)

```
insightEmailService.Setup(mock => mock.FindAndIncrementEmailForAccount(It.IsAny<Account>()))
                   .Verifiable();
```

Comment: i don't see how adding another abstraction here is going to reduce the complexity. The email sending *is* abstracted into a class that implements an interface already, I *am* using an interface already. The IInsightEmailService is a repository for loading InsightEmails. I could push the SystemReplyEmailSpec into the notifier, and that would reduce the dependencies to 5, but i'm not seeing a win. Why would putting another class around this (that does the same things) be better than using the code that is already there?

Answer (score 0):

When you do unit testing, you are just testing unit. It means under a given external dependencies , how is the unit (example a method calling methods from other services). Therefore , you need to see for various condition of the external dependency if your code under tests behaves right.

For methods that return nothing there are a number of ways to verify this

1. if you are using Mocking framework ,say for example Moq, you can use Verify to make sure that external methods are call with appropriate parameters.
2. You can verify what is passed to external methods using callbacks ( moq has good callback mechanism)